# Unable to run TOR from terminal (Ubuntu)

Tags: configuration, ubuntu

When I try to run TOR from the terminal, this message appears:

```
Jun 01 00:17:19.354 [notice] Tor 0.3.2.10 (git-0edaa32732ec8930) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0g, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd 1.3.3.
Jun 01 00:17:19.354 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jun 01 00:17:19.389 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jun 01 00:17:19.392 [notice] Scheduler type KIST has been enabled.
Jun 01 00:17:19.392 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jun 01 00:17:19.392 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Jun 01 00:17:19.392 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Jun 01 00:17:19.392 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

TOR is not running, and I have no idea how to solve this. Works perfectly if opened outside the terminal, though. I just want to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TOR is already running. Try to check tor status by running following command in terminal:

`sudo service tor status`

If it returns "tor is running", then tor is running.

Other possibilities:

1- try to start tor as super user

2- try to provide another config file